# weird git cherry-pick behaviour

Tags: git, cherry-pick, git-cherry-pick

I have a commit on a different branch that simply adds a bunch of files in a new directory.

Let's say the commit has id `123456` and it adds a directory called `foo` full of stuff.

Now in my other branch, from a clean working tree, I do `git cherry-pick 123456`, expecting it to just add the `foo` directory.

But no! the cherry pick fails and includes loads of other changes to other files(!) giving me unmerged paths.

Surely the commit you're cherry-picking must contain some stuff you didn't know about/expect, then? Well, no, `git show --oneline --name-status 123456 | grep -v foo` returns nothing. i.e. all there are no changes that happen to any files outside of `foo`.

**What is happening and how can I cherry pick this commit properly?**

Comment: It's not clear from the question whether "foo" was added over HEAD after cherry-pick. If not, try to run cherry-pick with -x flag - maybe you added different commit than the one you had intended.

Comment: @VasiliyZukanov the `foo` directory did not exist in the working tree at the time of issuing the cherry-pick (is that what you meant?). `-x` is only about the note that accompanies the new commit. I believe it to be an odd git bug (See my answer below).

Comment: I meant to ask whether `foo` ended up being added to the branch you executed cherry-pick from. Anyway, if upgrading Git resolved your issue - way to go.

Comment: @VasiliyZukanov you are correct. foo was not in the local branch checked out in the working tree. The intent was that it would be by cherry-picking.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade git.

**BAD:** git version 1.7.2.5 (as in Debian Squeeze) - guess Wheezy upgrade will fix it (has v1.7.10)

**GOOD:** git version 1.7.9.5 (as in Ubuntu Precise)